# How to tap on a element which is focused in appium. Unable to select value of a dropdown in appium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

I am facing an issue where the element of dropdown value is not showing in uiautomatorviewer.

While I have check the XML DOM by `getPageSource` of the screen and there also no value is been exposed of the results showing on mobile app screen

The XML snippet is as below:-

```
<android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.demo.pass" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,145][540,196]" resource-id="com.demo.pass:id/frameSearchLocation" instance="6">
    <android.widget.EditText index="0" text="Bryson City" class="android.widget.EditText" package="com.demo.pass" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="true" scrollable="false" long-clickable="true" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[30,145][510,196]" resource-id="com.demo.pass:id/autoCompleteSearchTextView" instance="0" />
    <android.widget.ImageView NAF="true" index="1" text="" class="android.widget.ImageView" package="com.demo.pass" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[457,148][502,193]" resource-id="com.demo.pass:id/imgCurrentLocation" instance="0" />
</android.widget.FrameLayout>
```

In a second thought, I tried keyboard operation. I am able to navigate to the value using below code

```
ad.pressKeyCode(20);
```

But I am not able to tap the value. I have tried most of the thing. Like:-

```
ad.pressKeyCode(66); // Press Enter
```

And

```
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(ad);
action.perform();
```

As there is no locator present on the DOM for dropdown values, I can't pass the element on above code.

As there is name as frame I also tried to switch using below code :-

```
ad.switchTo().frame(ad.findElement(By.xpath("com.demo.pass:id/frameSearchLocation")));
```

uiautomatorviewer screen :-

[image]

Please suggest what I should do in that case.
Any solution/suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this an hybrid app? Probably switchingContext in that case shall help you find the element. http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?java#automating-hybrid-apps

Comment: nup it is build on java android ..

Comment: the context that you're accessing doesn't seem to be completely native from the look of it. At this screen, could you try and fetch the contextHandles to check what all is listed by appium. It would provide better proof of the contexts available and if a switch might be required or not.

Comment: I have tried below code :-

Comment: ArrayList<String> contextName = new ArrayList<>();
   //Set contextName = ad.getContextHandles();
   System.out.println(contextName);
   for (String contexts : contextName) {
   System.out.println(contexts);
   if (contextName.contains("NATIVE_APP")) {
   System.out.println("Show me:" + contextName);
   Thread.sleep(1500);
   
   ad.context("NATIVE_APP");
   ad.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Bryson City, NC']")).click();
   }
   if (contextName.contains("WEBVIEW")) {
   ad.context("WEBVIEW");
   ad.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Bryson City, NC']")).click();
   }

Comment: getting empty [] .. source :- https://discuss.appium.io/t/how-to-switch-context-from-native-to-webview/14651/6

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Below code work for me

```
        By filter =By.xpath("MYLOCATOR");
        System.out.println("About to click on result");
        Point point = ad.findElement(filter).getLocation();
        int elementCenterX = point.getX() + 80;
        int elementCenterY = point.getY() + 100;
        System.out.println("value of x = "+elementCenterX+"   value of y = "+elementCenterY);
        ad.tap(2, elementCenterX , elementCenterY , 0);
```

Note:- you need to adjust X and Y as per your requirement in above code and pass the nearest locator like text box of the dropdown.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue. I have been doing Android App testing automation from last 2 years. I have encountered the same issue many times. Unfortunately, uiAutomator does not detect these kind of elements so we can't perform any actions on such elements.

Appium internally sends command to uiAutomator and uiAutomatar performs the actions on the device. uiAutomator can perform actions if uiAutomator sees those elements.

So I suggest you to don't spend much time on using TouchAction/java script/ pagesource or xPath because I have already tried hose solutions but none of them worked.

However, You can click on the elements using co-ordinates if the element is present at the same location every time (Not suggested if the elements in the drop down keep changing).

Comment: Thanks Vinod .. I have already done it using coordinates but looking for a alternative which will be more robust as you can't relay on co-ordinators .. even I can't verify the drop-down presence so it make automation more dangerous when it starting poping up false failure

Comment: If Google release the new version of UiAutomator, we can check with the newer version. As of now there is no way of detecting those elements.